# Mongo Auth failing on mongo:6.0.2 docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am running MongoDB in a docker container and am not able to authenticate with the user I have created. Please see the image with the example. [image]

Comment: You attempt to authenticate with user robert against the example database , but you have created it in the admin database ...

Comment: The examples says that if you define db in the "roles" as I did, that user will have that specific permissions on that DB.

Comment: The "examples" says it right , but maybe missing to say that you authencticate a user only to database where it is created , after authentication then authorisation apply for that user and grant the defined roles and permisions ... , for example if you do 1) use example and 2) createUser()  and 3) db.auth() then it will work as you expect ...